# check_mk : I can't access to my monitoring server after install

Tags: url, timeout, check-mk

I just installed a check_mk server, I've done this on other missions, but first time failed after creating a site. I checked with netstat and I have this:

> Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Adresse locale          Adresse distante
>   Etat        PID/Program name tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5000
>   0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      14925/httpd tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1/systemd tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*
>   LISTEN      962/sshd tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25
>   0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1318/master tcp6       0      0 :::111                  :::*                    LISTEN      1/systemd
>   tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*
>   LISTEN      962/sshd tcp6       0      0 ::1:25                  :::* 
>   LISTEN      1318/master

telnet on port 80 hangs, ping works, If you have experienced this or suggests are welcome.

Regards,
Hassane

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I found the solution, for my cas it was the local firewall which was blocking. Disabling it make all works.

Regards,
Hassane